# Display matched dates from range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using a Google Sheet to track student check-in's at school. The office staff would like to have an easy way to display all logged dates for any particular student. I would like to use Apps Script to programmatically display the information because `vlookup` and `index/match` get dicey with large data sets.

The problem is I can't seem to find a good solution using Apps Script:

- You can't run a script from a hyperlinked cell ("Get dates" or something similar to display a popup based on the row index)
- Comments/notes cannot be inserted in Apps Script
- Using Sheets formulas, wrong data is returned because of the high number of log entries.

Is there another method I'm missing? Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Did you try the Query formula?

Comment: @RobinGertenbach Yeah, I'd tried that, but given that some students may have 12+ entries, it also makes the sheet really long. Might be my only option, though.

Comment: You can always just get just the columns you need and group down to unique entries. If you provide I'd be happy to help

Comment: 1. "You can't run a script from a hyperlinked cell ('Get dates' or something similar to display a popup based on the row index)" actually you can, use custom menu, side panel, assign a script to an image, ...

Comment: 2. "Comments/notes cannot be inserted in Apps Script", actually, notes can be inserted.

Comment: @ruben where is the documentation for inserting notes? I can't find the appropriate methods anywhere.

Comment: 3. "Using Sheets formulas, wrong data is returned because of the high number of log entries." It's very likely that there is something wrong with the formulas that you tried, but it's impossible to be sure as there isn't any information about the formulas.

Comment: @BrianBennett: About the documentation, see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnotenote

Comment: No idea how I didn't find that page already. If you want to write it as an answer, I'd be happy to accept @ruben.

Comment: @BrianBennett: I posted an answer, but think that your questions doesn't follow the guidelines, because asking for "Any ideas..." is an opinion based question.

Comment: @ruben I thought the same, and almost didn't post. But, as your answer was just pointing me to documentation I couldn't find for the original idea, I think it's okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert a note use `range.setNote(note)`<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1</sup>: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnotenote